# How can I arrange two UILabels so that one autosizes and the other takes up the remaining space?

Tags: ios, uilabel, interface-builder

I have two labels arranged horizontally in my TableViewCell. The right should use as much space as it needs, while the one on the should left use up the remaining space.  In the case where the length of the two labels is greater than the width of the cell, the left label should be trimmed so that the right has enough space to fully display.  The labels are aligned to their respective sides, if that makes a difference.

The "Arrange > Fill Container Vertically" option under the Size Inspector is similar to what I need for the left label, but I want it to only occupy space not needed by the right label.

[image: Example]

If I add a constraint to the trailing space on the left label (see the third constraint below), the result is almost what I need, but instead of the right label being given the needed space, the left label takes the needed space (see final image).

[image: Constraints]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: You can do this programmatically by adding the right label first with a trailing anchor and no (or max) width anchor (use `sizeToFit` so the label's content becomes its intrinsic width) and then calculating its width in `layoutSubviews` and using that width as the (negative) constant for the left label's width anchor. With the programmatic approach, you can better account for edge cases regarding label widths and repositioning. This is basically what the compression and hugging API does behind the scenes but I prefer the control of doing it manually because there will never be any surprises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is easier than you might expect...

Constrain "LeftLabel" leading, constrain "RightLabel" trailing, constrain Horizontal Spacing between the two to `>= 8`, and then give "LeftLabel" a Content Compression Resistance Priority of `Low (250)`.

That tells auto-layout to expand each label based on its text content, but if the distance between them ends up being less-than 8, let "RightLabel" expand to its text, but expand "LeftLabel" only to the point that it is 8-pts from "RightLabel".

[image]

Left Label selected:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the content hugging priority and compression resistance priority. The right label should have a higher horizontal content hugging priority and content compression resistance priority than the left. This combined with the following constraints (written in visual format language) should give you the desired effect:

```
|-[leftLabel]-[rightLabel]-|
```

If the text in the right label is too long, this could cause the left label width to go to 0. Set a width constraint on the left label with a >= width to solve the issue.